# Merging Treemaps in a list

Tags: java

I have a `List<Map<String, Object>>` which contains the following maps.

```
Map:{clusterList=[71051], senseId=65786, totalCluster=1}
Map:{clusterList=[71051], senseId=65787, totalCluster=1}
Map:{clusterList=[4985, 71052], senseId=65788, totalCluster=2}
Map:{clusterList=[125840,153610,167812, 65787, 204091, 32586, 65786], senseId=71051, totalCluster=7}
Map:{clusterList=[11470, 65788], senseId=71052, totalCluster=2}
```

I have traversed the map and checked if senseId is present in the clusterList. But traversing each clusterList with senseId is taking long time with traditional for loop and also I am unable to get the merged list as the following

```
Map:{clusterList=[125840,153610,167812, 65787, 204091, 32586, 65786], senseId=71051, totalCluster=7}
Map:{clusterList=[4985,11470, 65788], senseId=71052, totalCluster=2}
```

I cant even remove the map with sensId present in the clusterList as it throws as concurrent operation exception.

Any ideas how to get to the result other than for loop as this list is very small so for loop still works. But I have list with 180 map entries and its hard to traverse the whole list and merge the maps.

I am stuck because the senseId of one map is present in clusterList of other map. So not able to merge them with simple search.

Comment: So you have the given List of Maps. Each map contains keys `"clusterList"` (whose value is a list of integers), and `"senseId"` (whose value is a single integer). And ... what do you want to do now? Find all maps with a certain `senseId`? This is not what you posted... Find all maps where the `senseID` is contained in the `clusterList`? This is *also* not what you posted...

Comment: I would like to merge those 5 maps into two maps. Dont bother about whether the value is integer or string in the clusterList. Consider it just as values. As you see int the 1st map senseId is 65786 which is already present in the clusterList of 4th map. So I want to keep this senseId 71051 as its clusterList has the senseId of the first 3 maps and merge the 1st three maps. The concept is senseId has its links in clusterList so duplicates should be remove or merged. Hope I have tried explaining what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm rather sure that the problem is still underspecified. For example, it is not clear how to decide about the final `senseId`. When you have two maps

```
Map:{clusterList=[123,456,789], senseId=123, totalCluster=1}
Map:{clusterList=[123,456,666], senseId=456, totalCluster=1}
```

then (if I understood you correctly) they should be merged. But it is not clear whether the result should be a map

```
Map:{clusterList=[123,456,789,666], senseId=123, totalCluster=1}
```

or a map

```
Map:{clusterList=[123,456,789,666], senseId=456, totalCluster=1}
```

Apart from that, it seems like the "totalCluster" is the size of the cluster list. This means that it is most likely unnecessary, and if it is *not* unnecessary, you'd have to specify how it should be treated when two maps are merged.

However, here is a basic approach: One can create a map from `senseId` to maps with this `senseId`, and afterwards collect the maps that contain a certain `senseId` in their cluster list in order to find out which maps have to be merged.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;


public class MapMergeTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Map<String, Object>> maps = createInput();

        System.out.println("Input:");
        for (Map<String, Object> map : maps)
        {
            System.out.println(map);
        }

        List<Map<String, Object>> result = createMergedMapsList(maps);

        System.out.println("Result:");
        for (Map<String, Object> map : result)
        {
            System.out.println(map);
        }
    }


    private static List<Map<String, Object>> createInput()
    {
        List<Map<String, Object>> maps = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        //                senseId  clusterList...
        maps.add(createMap(65786,  71051));
        maps.add(createMap(65787,  71051));
        maps.add(createMap(65788,  4985, 71052));
        maps.add(createMap(71051,  125840, 153610, 167812, 
            65787, 204091, 32586, 65786));
        maps.add(createMap(71052,  11470, 65788));
        return maps;
    }
    private static Map<String, Object> createMap(
        Integer senseId, Integer ... clusters)
    {
        Map<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        result.put("senseId", senseId);
        result.put("clusterList", new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(clusters)));
        return result;
    }



    private static List<Map<String, Object>> createMergedMapsList(
        List<Map<String, Object>> maps)
    {
        Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>> senseIdToMap =
            createSenseIdToMap(maps);

        Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>> copy = 
            new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Map<String,Object>>(senseIdToMap);
        for (Entry<Integer, Map<String, Object>> e : copy.entrySet())
        {
            Integer senseId = e.getKey();
            Map<String, Object> map = e.getValue();
            List<Integer> clusterList = getClusterList(map);
            List<Map<String, Object>> mapsToMerge = 
                new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
            mapsToMerge.add(map);
            for (Integer cluster : clusterList)
            {
                Map<String, Object> mapToMerge =
                    senseIdToMap.get(cluster);
                if (mapToMerge != null)
                {
                    mapsToMerge.add(mapToMerge);
                    senseIdToMap.remove(cluster);
                }
            }
            if (mapsToMerge.size() > 1)
            {
                Map<String, Object> mergedMap = mergeMaps(mapsToMerge);
                List<Integer> mergedClusterList = getClusterList(mergedMap);
                mergedClusterList.remove(senseId);
                senseIdToMap.put(senseId, mergedMap);
            }
        }
        return new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>(senseIdToMap.values());
    }

    private static Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>> createSenseIdToMap(
        List<Map<String, Object>> maps)
    {
        Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>> senseIdToMap = 
            new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Map<String,Object>>();
        for (Map<String, Object> map : maps)
        {
            Integer senseId = (Integer)map.get("senseId");
            senseIdToMap.put(senseId, map);
        }
        return senseIdToMap;
    }

    private static Map<String, Object> mergeMaps(List<Map<String, Object>> list)
    {
        Map<String, Object> mergedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        Map<String, Object> firstMap = list.get(0);
        mergedMap.put("senseId", firstMap.get("senseId"));
        Set<Integer> mergedClusterList = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
        for (Map<String, Object> map : list)
        {
            List<Integer> clusterList = getClusterList(map);
            mergedClusterList.addAll(clusterList);
        }
        mergedMap.put("clusterList", new ArrayList<Integer>(mergedClusterList));
        return mergedMap;
    }


    private static List<Integer> getClusterList(Map<String, Object> map)
    {
        Object object = map.get("clusterList");
        return (List<Integer>)object;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. This is what I wanted to do. The totalCluster will hold the length of the new clusterList. Thanks again .